# HTML5 canvas drawing application...x,y correct, but drawing is off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Have an odd problem with a 'Signature Pad" I'm building for an employment application...

The issue is that when you are at the left side of the canvas the line being drawn and the cursor line up...as you move towards the right side the the X chord being draw and the x chord of the cursor don't line up. The difference between the two grows as you move from left to right.  I have no multiplication in my code '*' only subtraction when dealing with Firefox.

**HTML**
*I did leave the other scripts/divs that will most likely be used once launched in there so you can see full code...I'm also including the js for those even though they should have no effect at the moment.*

```
<div id="container">
    <canvas id="imageView">
        <p>
            Unfortunately, your browser is currently unsupported by our web 
            application.  We are sorry for the inconvenience. Please use one of the 
            supported browsers listed below, or fill out a paper Signature release.
        </p>
        <p>
            Supported browsers:<br /> 
            <a href="http://www.opera.com/browser/download/">Opera Browser</a> 
            <a href="http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/features/">Firefox</a>
            <a href="http://www.apple.com/safari/download/">Safari</a>
            <a href="http://www.konqueror.org/download/">Konqueror (Linux PC)</a>
        </p>
    </canvas><!--
    <div id="SigCover"></div>
    <div id="SigCoverText"><span><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Signature Saved</span></div>
    <div class="ClearBoth"></div>-->
</div>
<form action="">
    <input type="button" value="Save Signature" onclick="SaveImage()" />
    <input type="button" value="Reset Signature" onclick="ResetSignature()" />
</form>
<div id="ImageToSave"></div>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Signature/canvas2image.js")"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Signature/Signature.js")"></script><!--
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Signature/SaveSignature.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Signature/ResetSignature.js")"></script>-->
```

**Signature/Drawing js...**

```
var points = new Array();
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var canvas, context, tool;

        function init() {
            // Find the canvas element.
            canvas = document.getElementById('imageView');
            if (!canvas) {
                alert('Error: I cannot find the canvas element!');
                return;
            }

            if (!canvas.getContext) {
                alert('Error: no canvas.getContext!');
                return;
            }

            // Get the 2D canvas context.
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            if (!context) {
                alert('Error: failed to getContext!');
                return;
            }

            // Pencil tool instance.
            tool = new tool_pencil();

            // Attach the mousedown, mousemove and mouseup event listeners.
            canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', ev_canvas, false);
        }

        // This painting tool works like a drawing pencil which tracks the mouse 
        // movements.
        function tool_pencil() {
            var tool = this;
            this.started = false;

            // This is called when you start holding down the mouse button.
            // This starts the pencil drawing.
            this.mousedown = function (ev) {
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(ev._x, ev._y);
                tool.started = true;
            };

            // This function is called every time you move the mouse. Obviously, it only 
            // draws if the tool.started state is set to true (when you are holding down 
            // the mouse button).
            this.mousemove = function (ev) {
                if (tool.started) {
                    context.lineTo(ev._x, ev._y);
                    context.stroke();
                }
            };

            // This is called when you release the mouse button.
            this.mouseup = function (ev) {
                if (tool.started) {
                    tool.mousemove(ev);
                    tool.started = false;
                }
            };
        }
        // The general-purpose event handler. This function just determines the mouse 
        // position relative to the canvas element.
        function ev_canvas(ev) {
            if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' || navigator.vendor == 'Google Inc.' || navigator.vendor == 'Apple Computer, Inc.') { // IE or Chrome
                ev._x = ev.offsetX;
                ev._y = ev.offsetY;
            } else if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { // Firefox
                ev._x = ev.layerX - this.offsetLeft;
                ev._y = ev.layerY - this.offsetTop;
            } else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) { // Opera
                ev._x = ev.offsetX;
                ev._y = ev.offsetY;
            }
            // Call the event handler of the tool.
            var func = tool[ev.type];
            if (func) {
                func(ev);
            }
            points.push(ev);
        }

        init();

    }, false);
}
```

**Reset Signature js...**

```
function ResetSignature() {
    var canvasReset = document.getElementById('imageView');
    var contextReset = canvasReset.getContext('2d');

    contextReset.fillStyle = '#000000';
    contextReset.fillRect(0, 0, $('imageView').css('width'), $('imageView').css('height'));
    canvasReset.width = canvasReset.width;
    canvasReset.width = canvasReset.width;

    alert(points.length);
    points = new Array();
}
```

**Save Signature js (uses Canvas2Image lib)**

```
function SaveImage() {
    var CanvasToSave = document.getElementById('imageView');

    var oImg = Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(CanvasToSave, true);

    $('#ImageToSave').html(oImg);

    $('#SigCover').css('z-index', 102);
    $('#SigCover').css('left', 23);
    $('#SigCover').css('width', 402);
    $('#SigCover').css('height', 152);
    $('#SigCoverText').css('z-index', 101);
    $('#SigCoverText').css('left', 23);
    $('#SigCoverText').css('width', 400);
    $('#SigCoverText').css('height', 150);
    alert(points.length);
}
```

**Lastly the CSS**

```
#imageView
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    z-index: 100;
}/*

#SigCover
{
    background-color: Gray;
    opacity: .5;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 57px;
    left: -4000px;
    z-index: -1;
    float: left;
}

#SigCoverText
{
    background-color: Gray;
    opacity: .5;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 57px;
    left: -4000px;
    z-index: -1;
    float: left;
}
```

I just can't find what is causing the X choord variance to exponentially grow like it is...the Y choord is fine throughout and has no variance.  Pulling my hair out here!!!

EDIT:  I'm including images to show you what I'm talking about the large(r) black dots are the approx location of cursor the top image is pretty much spot on and the bottom image you can see that the cursor is far to the left of where it should be.

[image: Image showing correct cursor position towards left of canvas]

[image: Image showing incorrect cursor position towards right of canvas]

EDIT 2: As requested this has been put into jsFiddle...
[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/KtuRA/1/)

Comment: I'd suggest to put all this code in jsfiddle

Comment: Done thanks for suggesting that...I always forget about it, but love it when others include it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use canvas.width and canvas.height to size your canvas, **NOT** CSS width/height.

Here you are merely stretching the canvas:

```
#imageView
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

And you do not want to do that.

Here it is fixed:

http://jsfiddle.net/KtuRA/5/

Comment: +1 Been battling this scaling issue for the last while, and didn't realize I needed to modify the width and height of the canvas element, and not the CSS styling of the element. Thanks!

Comment: @SimonSarris  happen to know if it will cause issues to set both values?  I'm using the css properties in js so would like to keep both

Comment: it shouldn't be an issue to set both, but you probably shouldn't do it unless you really, really have to.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the Simon Sarris answer with one additional detail. Just in case you do not want to specify canvas height and width and want it to take the height of the parent, then to refrain your drawings to be off the point of interest, add following line of code in init function

```
canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
```

Furthermore for calculating accurate ev._x and ev._y, do read this post, its helpful when document structure is complex

[Tracking mouse position in canvas when no surrounding element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085689/tracking-mouse-position-in-canvas-when-no-surrounding-element-exists/5086147#5086147)

Answer (score 0):

Add the scroll Top and scroll Left,because at the time of scrolling we should add these factors.  Try the below code it could be helpful for you.

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas,ctx,flag=false,prevX=0,currX=0,prevY=0,currY=0,dot_flag=false;
    var x="black",y=2;
    function init()
    {
        canvas=document.getElementById('can');
        ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        w=canvas.width;
        h=canvas.height;

        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){ findxy('move',e)  },false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",function(e){ findxy('down',e)  },false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup",function(e){ findxy('up',e)  },false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout",function(e){ findxy('out',e)  },false);
    } 
    function color(obj)
    {
        switch(obj.id)
        {
            case "green" : x="green";break;
            case "blue" : x="blue";break;
            case "red" : x="red";break;
            case "yellow" : x="yellow";break;
            case "orange" : x="orange";break;
            case "black" : x="black";break;
            case "white" : x="white";break;
        }
        if(x=="white")y=14;
        else y=2;

    }
    function draw()
    {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX,prevY);
        ctx.lineTo(currX,currY);
        ctx.strokeStyle=x;
        ctx.lineWidth=y;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    function erase()
    {
        var m=confirm("Want to clear");
        if(m)
        {
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display="none";
        }
    }
    function save()
    {
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border="2px solid";
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display="inline";
     }
    function findxy(res,e)
    {

        if(res=='down')
                    {   prevX=currX;prevY=currY;
                        currX=e.clientX-canvas.offsetLeft;
                        currY=e.clientY-canvas.offsetTop; 

                        flag=true;
                        dot_flag=true;
                        if(dot_flag)
                        {
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.fillStyle=x;
                        ctx.fillRect(currX,currY,2,2);
                        ctx.closePath();
                        dot_flag=false;
                        }
                        }
                if(res=='up'||res=="out")
                {
                    flag=false; 
                } 
                if(res=='move')
                {

                    if(flag)
                    {
                    prevX=currX;
                    prevY=currY;
                    currX=e.clientX-canvas.offsetLeft;
                    currY=e.clientY-canvas.offsetTop;
                draw();
                    }
                }
    }

    </script>

    <body onload="init()">
            <canvas id="can" width="400"height="400" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:10%;border:2px solid;"></canvas>

            <div style="position:absolute;top:12%;left:43%;">Choose Color</div>
            <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:45%;width:10px;height:10px;background:green;" id="green" onclick="color(this)"></div>
            <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:46%;width:10px;height:10px;background:blue;" id="blue" onclick="color(this)"></div>
            <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:47%;width:10px;height:10px;background:red;" id="red" onclick="color(this)"></div>
            <div style="position:absolute;top:17%;left:45%;width:10px;height:10px;background:yellow;" id="yellow" onclick="color(this)"></div>
            <div style="position:absolute;top:17%;left:46%;width:10px;height:10px;background:orange;" id="orange" onclick="color(this)"></div>
            <div style="position:absolute;top:17%;left:47%;width:10px;height:10px;background:black;" id="black" onclick="color(this)"></div>
            <div style="position:absolute;top:20%;left:43%;">Eraser</div>
            <div style="position:absolute;top:22%;left:45%;width:15px;height:15px;background:white;border:2px solid;" id="white" onclick="color(this)"></div>

            <img id="canvasimg"style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:52%;" style="display:none;">
        <input type="button" value="save" id="btn" size="30" onclick="save()"style="position:absolute;top:55%;left:10%;">
        <input type="button" value="clear" id="clr" size="23" onclick="erase()"style="position:absolute;top:55%;left:15%;">
    </body>
</html>
```