# HTML5 Canvas Mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, onclick, mouseevent

I have an HTML file with a `<canvas>` element and I am trying to get the mouse coordinates in the `click` event. I am using this code:

```
secondCanvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.pageX)
}, false);
```

When I click on the top left point I get in console 500~ number, not zero... what do I need to do to get the coordinates of the mouse on the canvas?

Answer (score 3):

You should calculate the canvas mouse position by substracting the canvas element offset from the event offset (`e.pageX` and `e.pageY`).
Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/dynamically-retrieve-html-element-x-y-position-with-javascript) that explains how to get an element position in the dom, and the code should look like :

```
secondCanvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   var pos = {
       x : e.pageX - canvasOffsetX,
       y : e.pageY - canvasOffsetY
   };
   console.log(pos.x)
}, false);
```

Comment: +1  To get the offset, unless you need to support old browsers, I'd suggest using `element.getBoundingClientRect();` which returns an object with top bottom left right properties

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're getting page coordinates. I'm guessing you want the current mouse position within either one of your two canvases? Hopefully this will solve your problem:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/

Also this stackoverflow is similar to yours and might give you a better understanding:
[Tracking mouse position in canvas when no surrounding element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085689/tracking-mouse-position-in-canvas)

## Solution by user: lwburk

```
function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = 0, curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
    }
    return undefined;
}

$('#canvas').mousemove(function(e) {
    var pos = findPos(this);
    var x = e.pageX - pos.x;
    var y = e.pageY - pos.y;
    var coordinateDisplay = "x=" + x + ", y=" + y;
    writeCoordinateDisplay(coordinateDisplay);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this code and it works perfectly for me. Once added, canvas mouse events have two new properties: canvasX, and canvasY which are properly mapped. Right after you obtained the canvas element, don't forget to call canvas.extendMouseEvents() and you're in business.

```
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.extendMouseEvents = function() {
    this.mapMouseEvent = function(ev) {
        var r = this.getBoundingClientRect();
        ev.canvasX = ev.pageX - r.left;
        ev.canvasY = ev.pageY - r.top;
    };
    this.addEventListener("mousemove", this.mapMouseEvent);
    this.addEventListener("click", this.mapMouseEvent);
    this.addEventListener("contextmenu", this.mapMouseEvent);
    this.addEventListener("dblclick", this.mapMouseEvent);
    this.addEventListener("mousedown", this.mapMouseEvent);
    this.addEventListener("mouseenter", this.mapMouseEvent);
    this.addEventListener("mouseleave", this.mapMouseEvent);
    this.addEventListener("mouseover", this.mapMouseEvent);
    this.addEventListener("mouseout", this.mapMouseEvent);
    this.addEventListener("mouseup", this.mapMouseEvent);
}
```

Comment: i fix it to deal directly with the canvas itself without touching the context.