# How to get cursor coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to make a drawing application (just for fun)

And I cloud not figure out a way of getting the cursor's coordinates when the user clicks and holds on a canvas element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Canvas Mouse coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403214/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates)

Comment: Additional duplicate: [How do I get the coordinates of a mouse click on a canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55677)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify. When are you wanting to get the cursor's coordinates? When it moves? When you click? Are you wanting the coordinates relative to the document, or the canvas?

Comment: So, you want to get the coordinates between: when the user presses down on the (main) mouse button through when they release that mouse button. Is that correct? Do you want the coordinates relative to the page, or the canvas? It would help significantly if you were to supply the HTML which you have for the page, or at least the part which is the canvas.