# Reading the RGB value of a canvas pixel

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have put an image in canvas and I want to get the RGB value of the pixels of that image  when the user moves the mouse over the image. Here is the code which I have written:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border: red;border-style: dotted">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var destX = 0;
var destY = 0;

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function()
{
context.drawImage(imageObj, destX, destY);
};
imageObj.src = "zain.jpg";

canvas.onclick = function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    var canvasColor = context.getImageData(x, y, 1,1); // rgba e [0,255]
    var pixels = canvasColor.data;
    var r = pixels[0];
    var g = pixels[1];
    var b = pixels[2];
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+r+','+g+','+b+")";
}
```

Comment: Two quick comments about your current code. 1. Make sure getImageData w and h are set to 1 instead (getImageData(x, y, 1, 1). 2. Set CSS like this "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")"; . You'll need to format the output like this to match the spec.

Comment: @bebraw i have updated the code, but still nothing happening, my code is not executing right after the getImageData() functional call. Can you please do me a favor, that you copy my code and just run it at your end. Shall be very thankful to you!

Comment: Your code appears to work here. There's one important thing to keep in mind, though! You will need to run the script on a local server. Otherwise getImageData will give you SECURITY_ERR (inspect your console for this).

Comment: i am running it on my local machine, but i dont know why my code is not executing right after the getImageData() call. :(

Comment: yes you are right it is giving the Security error right after the getImageData() function call, can you suggest me, how to handle with it?

Comment: It worked, i have handled the exceptions by try catch :) thanks alot

Answer (score 9):

Try something along this:

```
var color = document.getElementById("color");
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(imageObj, destX, destY);
};
imageObj.src = "zain.jpg";

canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    // not so sure about these... might need to offset them or so
    var x = e.x;
    var y = e.y;

    // set color now
    var canvasColor = context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data; // rgba e [0,255]
    var r = canvasColor[0];
    var g = canvasColor[1];
    var b = canvasColor[2];

    color.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
}
```

Note that the snippet expects you have a div with id "color" somewhere. It sets the pixel color there.

Comment: There's some info about the mouse coordinate problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848310/getting-mouse-position-with-javascript-within-canvas .

Comment: By using your code, the image which i was pushing in canvas is also not showing now, kindly help me out please.

Comment: i have updated the code, please have look, but still same problem i am not receiving the RGB value

Comment: getImageData() returns an ImageData object, not an array. When you access canvasColor[0...2] it doesn't contain anything. You need to access canvasColor.data[0...2] instead.

Comment: Excellent point. Added that. I usually use my own Canvas wrapper instead of the pure API. ;)

Comment: Understandable. Just getting a handle to the context is annoying enough! :)

Comment: @using canvasColor.data[0] still not returning me anything :(

Comment: hi, i have checked it out code line                                 var canvasColor = context.getImageData(x, y, w, h); // rgba e [0,255] is not working, i don't know whats happening, kindly help me out

Comment: As far as I can tell, `w` and `h` are not defined in your call to `getImageData()`. All you need is one pixel, so you can hardcode values of `1` in there. Also, I'm not quite sure why you now have the comment in your post about the browser not supporting the canvas element. If your browser doesn't support the canvas element, you can't do any of this.

Comment: @Xenethyl.. Browser is completely supporting my canvas, there is no issue of browser support. just the getImageData() function is not working

Comment: can anyone please suggest me the complete code in running condition. shall be very thankful

Comment: @Zain : It's important you call getImageData like this: getImageData(x, y, 1, 1). This returns the data of the given pixel. There's no need to pass w and h there in this case.

Comment: @bebraw i have updated the code, but still nothing happening, my code is not executing right after the getImageData()  functional call. Can you please do me a favor, that you copy my code and just run it at your end. Shall be very thankful to you!

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for here is the [getImageData()](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#pixel-manipulation) call.

So, your solution would look something like this:

```
function getColor(canvas, x, y) {    
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var pixel = context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);

    // Red = rgb[0], green = rgb[1], blue = rgb[2]
    // All colors are within range [0, 255]
    var rgb = pixel.data;

    return rgb;
}

function canvasMouseMove(e) {
    var x = e.layerX, y = e.layerY;
    var rgb = getColor(canvas, x, y);
    var rgb_string = "rgb(" + rgb[0] + "," + rgb[1] + "," + rgb[2] + ")";

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = rgb_string;
}

canvas.onmousemove = canvasMouseMove;
```

As @bebraw pointed out, you may need to handle the mouse location differently depending on the browser being used. For that, you might consider using jQuery or another JS library for simplicity.