# Reading RGB from Image In Canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, image, canvas

I am trying to read RGB from an image In canvas.

1. I create a canvas and its context
2. I ll read img.width and img.height & set the same dimensions to the canvas
3. Draw the image in canvas
4. Read the imagedata using getImageData()
5. when I see the RGB values as Red = 0, Green = 0, Blue = 0  for all the pixels of image.

   ```
        <html>
        <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function myfun() {
       var img = document.getElementById('myImg');

       var width = img.clientWidth;
       var height = img.clientHeight;


       var _grayCanvas = document.getElementById('grayCanvas');
       var grayctx = _grayCanvas.getContext("2d");

       grayctx.canvas.width = width;
       grayctx.canvas.height = height;


       var grayimg = new Image();
       grayimg.src = "img.bmp";



       grayimg.onload = function () {
           grayctx.drawImage(grayimg, 0, 0);
       }



       var x = 0;
       var y = 0;
       var canvasColor = grayctx.getImageData(x, y, width, hieght);

       var red = canvasColor.data[0];
       var green = canvasColor.data[1];
       var blue = canvasColor.data[2];
       var alpha = canvasColor.data[3];

       alert(red + " : " + green + " : " + blue + " : " + alpha);


       for (var i = 0; i < canvasColor.data.length ; i += 4) {
           var red = canvasColor[i];
           var green = canvasColor[i + 1];
           var blue = canvasColor[i + 2];
           var alpha = canvasColor[i + 3];
           if(red > 0)
           alert(red + " : " + green + " : " + blue + " : " + alpha);
       }

   }
   ```

What might be the issue with respect to the above code ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373851/help-to-read-the-rgb-value-of-an-image-using-html5

Comment: `canvasColor.length` should be `canvasColor.data.length`. It will only be 4, since you've just asked for 1 pixel. Therefore, your for loop is nonsense too! I.e You can only index from [0..3], yet you try to index from [0..6] (i=0 + 3) up to (i=3 + 3).

Comment: But do you see the image on the canvas?

Comment: Here's a code example that reads all the pixels on an image:  http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-tutorial/