# Use a Canvas to select a portion of a pdf document

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html5-canvas

I have a request to select a portion of a pdf document and save/email that generated image in an ASP.NET website. My initial thought was to load the pdf document and then utilize a draggable/resizable canvas to select a portion of the document and save it out. Does anyone know how to accomplish this or know of an alternative method of doing this.

I visualize a draggable/resizable box that they can move around a multipage document and select a save a portion of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest looking at Mozilla's [pdf.js project](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js).  It renders PDFs to a canvas for you.  So you can then capture which section you want with your mouse, and copy out the image data:

```
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var image = context.getImageData(x, y, width, height);
```

In order to get mouse positions inside of a canvas, checkout thess SO questions: [getting mouse position with javascript within canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848310/getting-mouse-position-with-javascript-within-canvas) and [Draw on HTML5 Canvas using a mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368784/draw-by-mouse-with-html5-canvas)